# Apache Cassandra 3.11.2 - errors on startup

Tags: cassandra, java-8, windows-10, cassandra-3.0

I have suddenly encountered some errors (Java exceptions) on startup of my Apache Cassandra 3.11.2 database on Windows 10. I didn't have such errors before on that version of the database. Here is an excerpt from my `debug.log` file:

```
DEBUG [SSTableBatchOpen:1] 2018-05-21 13:42:39,806 SSTableReader.java:504 - Opening C:\Users\Michał\Downloads\apache-cassandra-3.11.2\data\data\system\IndexInfo-9f5c6374d48532299a0a5094af9ad1e3\mc-53-big (0,139KiB)
ERROR [SSTableBatchOpen:1] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,092 DebuggableThreadPoolExecutor.java:239 - Error in ThreadPoolExecutor
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/LocalCacheFactory$WISWR
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$BoundedLocalManualCache.<init>(BoundedLocalCache.java:2727) ~[caffeine-2.2.6.jar:na]
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$BoundedLocalLoadingCache.<init>(BoundedLocalCache.java:2944) ~[caffeine-2.2.6.jar:na]
        at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine.build(Caffeine.java:830) ~[caffeine-2.2.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cache.ChunkCache.<init>(ChunkCache.java:145) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cache.ChunkCache.<clinit>(ChunkCache.java:47) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.load(SSTableReader.java:763) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.load(SSTableReader.java:737) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:517) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:385) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader$3.run(SSTableReader.java:564) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:81) [apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCacheFactory$WISWR
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:370) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Resource.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:462) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
DEBUG [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,119 DiskBoundaryManager.java:53 - Refreshing disk boundary cache for system.IndexInfo
DEBUG [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,136 DiskBoundaryManager.java:92 - Got local ranges [] (ringVersion = 0)
DEBUG [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,138 DiskBoundaryManager.java:56 - Updating boundaries from null to DiskBoundaries{directories=[DataDirectory{location=C:\Users\Michał\Downloads\apache-cassandra-3.11.2\data\data}], positions=null, ringVersion=0, directoriesVersion=0} for system.IndexInfo
INFO  [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,154 ColumnFamilyStore.java:411 - Initializing system.batches
INFO  [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,166 ColumnFamilyStore.java:411 - Initializing system.paxos
DEBUG [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,168 DiskBoundaryManager.java:53 - Refreshing disk boundary cache for system.paxos
DEBUG [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,168 DiskBoundaryManager.java:92 - Got local ranges [] (ringVersion = 0)
DEBUG [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,168 DiskBoundaryManager.java:56 - Updating boundaries from null to DiskBoundaries{directories=[DataDirectory{location=C:\Users\Michał\Downloads\apache-cassandra-3.11.2\data\data}], positions=null, ringVersion=0, directoriesVersion=0} for system.paxos
INFO  [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,184 ColumnFamilyStore.java:411 - Initializing system.local
DEBUG [SSTableBatchOpen:1] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,189 SSTableReader.java:504 - Opening C:\Users\Michał\Downloads\apache-cassandra-3.11.2\data\data\system\local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377\mc-187-big (5,049KiB)
ERROR [SSTableBatchOpen:1] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,189 DebuggableThreadPoolExecutor.java:239 - Error in ThreadPoolExecutor
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.cassandra.cache.ChunkCache
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.load(SSTableReader.java:763) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.load(SSTableReader.java:737) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:517) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:385) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader$3.run(SSTableReader.java:564) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:81) [apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
DEBUG [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,190 DiskBoundaryManager.java:53 - Refreshing disk boundary cache for system.local
DEBUG [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,190 DiskBoundaryManager.java:92 - Got local ranges [] (ringVersion = 0)
DEBUG [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,190 DiskBoundaryManager.java:56 - Updating boundaries from null to DiskBoundaries{directories=[DataDirectory{location=C:\Users\Michał\Downloads\apache-cassandra-3.11.2\data\data}], positions=null, ringVersion=0, directoriesVersion=0} for system.local
INFO  [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,201 ColumnFamilyStore.java:411 - Initializing system.peers
DEBUG [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,202 DiskBoundaryManager.java:53 - Refreshing disk boundary cache for system.peers
DEBUG [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,202 DiskBoundaryManager.java:92 - Got local ranges [] (ringVersion = 0)
DEBUG [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,202 DiskBoundaryManager.java:56 - Updating boundaries from null to DiskBoundaries{directories=[DataDirectory{location=C:\Users\Michał\Downloads\apache-cassandra-3.11.2\data\data}], positions=null, ringVersion=0, directoriesVersion=0} for system.peers
INFO  [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,211 ColumnFamilyStore.java:411 - Initializing system.peer_events
DEBUG [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,213 DiskBoundaryManager.java:53 - Refreshing disk boundary cache for system.peer_events
DEBUG [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,213 DiskBoundaryManager.java:92 - Got local ranges [] (ringVersion = 0)
DEBUG [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,213 DiskBoundaryManager.java:56 - Updating boundaries from null to DiskBoundaries{directories=[DataDirectory{location=C:\Users\Michał\Downloads\apache-cassandra-3.11.2\data\data}], positions=null, ringVersion=0, directoriesVersion=0} for system.peer_events
INFO  [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,223 ColumnFamilyStore.java:411 - Initializing system.range_xfers
DEBUG [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,224 DiskBoundaryManager.java:53 - Refreshing disk boundary cache for system.range_xfers
DEBUG [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,224 DiskBoundaryManager.java:92 - Got local ranges [] (ringVersion = 0)
DEBUG [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,224 DiskBoundaryManager.java:56 - Updating boundaries from null to DiskBoundaries{directories=[DataDirectory{location=C:\Users\Michał\Downloads\apache-cassandra-3.11.2\data\data}], positions=null, ringVersion=0, directoriesVersion=0} for system.range_xfers
INFO  [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,237 ColumnFamilyStore.java:411 - Initializing system.compaction_history
DEBUG [SSTableBatchOpen:1] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,244 SSTableReader.java:504 - Opening C:\Users\Michał\Downloads\apache-cassandra-3.11.2\data\data\system\compaction_history-b4dbb7b4dc493fb5b3bfce6e434832ca\mc-32-big (3,121KiB)
DEBUG [SSTableBatchOpen:2] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,244 SSTableReader.java:504 - Opening C:\Users\Michał\Downloads\apache-cassandra-3.11.2\data\data\system\compaction_history-b4dbb7b4dc493fb5b3bfce6e434832ca\mc-33-big (0,354KiB)
ERROR [SSTableBatchOpen:2] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,244 DebuggableThreadPoolExecutor.java:239 - Error in ThreadPoolExecutor
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.cassandra.cache.ChunkCache
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.load(SSTableReader.java:763) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.load(SSTableReader.java:737) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:517) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:385) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader$3.run(SSTableReader.java:564) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:81) [apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
ERROR [SSTableBatchOpen:1] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,245 DebuggableThreadPoolExecutor.java:239 - Error in ThreadPoolExecutor
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.cassandra.cache.ChunkCache
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.load(SSTableReader.java:763) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.load(SSTableReader.java:737) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:517) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:385) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader$3.run(SSTableReader.java:564) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:81) [apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
DEBUG [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,246 DiskBoundaryManager.java:53 - Refreshing disk boundary cache for system.compaction_history
DEBUG [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,246 DiskBoundaryManager.java:92 - Got local ranges [] (ringVersion = 0)
DEBUG [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,246 DiskBoundaryManager.java:56 - Updating boundaries from null to DiskBoundaries{directories=[DataDirectory{location=C:\Users\Michał\Downloads\apache-cassandra-3.11.2\data\data}], positions=null, ringVersion=0, directoriesVersion=0} for system.compaction_history
INFO  [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,262 ColumnFamilyStore.java:411 - Initializing system.sstable_activity
DEBUG [SSTableBatchOpen:2] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,268 SSTableReader.java:504 - Opening C:\Users\Michał\Downloads\apache-cassandra-3.11.2\data\data\system\sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e\mc-40-big (1,243KiB)
DEBUG [SSTableBatchOpen:1] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,268 SSTableReader.java:504 - Opening C:\Users\Michał\Downloads\apache-cassandra-3.11.2\data\data\system\sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e\mc-39-big (0,778KiB)
ERROR [SSTableBatchOpen:2] 2018-05-21 13:42:40,269 DebuggableThreadPoolExecutor.java:239 - Error in ThreadPoolExecutor
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.cassandra.cache.ChunkCache
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.load(SSTableReader.java:763) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.load(SSTableReader.java:737) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:517) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:385) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader$3.run(SSTableReader.java:564) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:81) [apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
(...)
ERROR [main] 2018-05-21 13:42:51,336 CassandraDaemon.java:708 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.cassandra.cache.ChunkCache
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFuture(FBUtilities.java:385) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.forceBlockingFlush(SystemKeyspace.java:819) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.removeTruncationRecord(SystemKeyspace.java:670) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.invalidate(ColumnFamilyStore.java:553) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.invalidate(ColumnFamilyStore.java:529) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.LegacySchemaMigrator.lambda$unloadLegacySchemaTables$1(LegacySchemaMigrator.java:137) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.LegacySchemaMigrator.unloadLegacySchemaTables(LegacySchemaMigrator.java:137) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.LegacySchemaMigrator.migrate(LegacySchemaMigrator.java:83) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:256) [apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:602) [apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:691) [apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.cassandra.cache.ChunkCache
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFuture(FBUtilities.java:381) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.cassandra.cache.ChunkCache
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter.<init>(BigTableWriter.java:64) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigFormat$WriterFactory.open(BigFormat.java:92) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableWriter.create(SSTableWriter.java:102) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SimpleSSTableMultiWriter.create(SimpleSSTableMultiWriter.java:119) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionStrategy.createSSTableMultiWriter(AbstractCompactionStrategy.java:587) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionStrategyManager.createSSTableMultiWriter(CompactionStrategyManager.java:1027) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createSSTableMultiWriter(ColumnFamilyStore.java:518) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.createFlushWriter(Memtable.java:504) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.<init>(Memtable.java:443) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.<init>(Memtable.java:420) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.createFlushRunnables(Memtable.java:307) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.flushRunnables(Memtable.java:298) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore$Flush.flushMemtable(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1140) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore$Flush.run(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1105) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:81) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
```

Is this issue caused by an old version of JDK or rather by Cassandra? How can I address it?

Comment: Wow, 1.8.0_60 is like...three years old!  I think bumping-up your JDK version is *definitely* something to start with.

Comment: @Aaron , done. The error still occurs, but the upgrade was something to start with. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After Windows reboot, these errors no longer occur.

Comment: Well, glad to know you got it working.  Cassandra on Windows can be tricky.